# Reshape a pandas dataframe and make the first column the header and pivot all the data on it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like below;

[initial dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuUvt.png)

Would like to rotate make the values on the first column the headers(basically to below output

[Output I'd like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnAC4.png)

Comment: please read [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51193459/python-pandas-convert-a-column-to-column-header